# Problem with creating dataset for visual object tracker

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, tracking, training-data

I wanted to train [ET-Track](https://github.com/pblatter/ettrack/tree/main/pytracking)(a nice video object tracker). which is based on [Ocean](https://github.com/researchmm/TracKit)(another video object tracker).

the problem is they did not share any code for training it before. now we have the code(changing codes from Ocean) but we have a big problem with it. we have a random shift when trying to crop images for our template-image. this is an example:

[image: crop results]

as you can see the search2 image which the model will train with it have a shift in it. I can figure out why I have this shift. would you help me please?

```
        (template,search,out_label,reg_label,reg_weight,bbox,) = dataset[0]
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, bbox)            
        search = search.transpose((1, 2, 0)).astype(np.uint8)
        
        search = cv2.rectangle((search) , (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (200, 100, 150),1)
        
        reg_weight = cv2.cvtColor(reg_weight.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
        reg_weight = cv2.resize(reg_weight, (search.shape[1], search.shape[0]))
        out_label = cv2.cvtColor(out_label.astype(np.uint8) * 255, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
        out_label = cv2.resize(out_label, (search.shape[1], search.shape[0]))
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, bbox)
        search2 = cv2.rectangle(search * reg_weight, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (200, 100, 150))
        cv2.imshow("search2", search2)
        cv2.imshow("search",search)
        cv2.imshow("out_label", out_label)
```

This is how these outputs are created.

and this is my dataset `__getitem__`:

```
        if self.random_data:
             template, search = self._get_pairs(index)
             #choose 2 random image for search and template
        
        template_image = cv2.imread(template[0].as_posix())
        search_image = cv2.imread(search[0].as_posix())
        # change bboxes format and pick the first one
        template_target_bbox = self.yolo2ocean(template[1], template_image)
        search_target_bbox = self.yolo2ocean(search[1], search_image)
        _, template_image = crop_like_SiamFC(
            template_image,
            bbox=template_target_bbox,
            exemplar_size=self.template_size,
            instance_size=self.search_size,
        )
        _, search_image = crop_like_SiamFC(
            search_image,
            bbox=search_target_bbox,
            exemplar_size=self.template_size,
            instance_size=self.search_size + self.search_margin,
        )
        template_box = self._toBBox(template_image, template_target_bbox)
        search_box = self._toBBox(search_image, search_target_bbox)

        template, _, _ = self._augmentation(
            template_image, template_box, self.template_size
        )
        search, bbox, dag_param = self._augmentation(
            search_image, search_box, self.search_size, search=True
        )
        #No augment i have turned off all of them! 
        # from PIL image to numpy
        template = np.array(template)
        search = np.array(search)
        out_label = self._dynamic_label([self.size, self.size], dag_param.shift)

        reg_label, reg_weight = self.reg_label(bbox)
```

I think the `self.reg_label` is actual problem but I don't know why?
this is the function:

```
def reg_label(self, bbox):
        """
        generate regression label
        :param bbox: [x1, y1, x2, y2]
        :return: [l, t, r, b]
        """
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
        l = self.grid_to_search_x - x1  # [17, 17]
        t = self.grid_to_search_y - y1
        r = x2 - self.grid_to_search_x
        b = y2 - self.grid_to_search_y
        l, t, r, b = map(lambda x: np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), [l, t, r, b])
        
        
        reg_label = np.concatenate((l, t, r, b), axis=-1)  # [17, 17, 4]
        reg_label_min = np.min(reg_label, axis=-1)
        inds_nonzero = (reg_label_min > 0).astype(float)

        return reg_label, inds_nonzero
def grids(self):
        """
        each element of feature map on input search image
        :return: H*W*2 (position for each element)
        """
        sz = self.size #25

        sz_x = sz // 2
        sz_y = sz // 2

        x, y = np.meshgrid(
            np.arange(0, sz) - np.floor(float(sz_x)),
            np.arange(0, sz) - np.floor(float(sz_y)),
        )
        self.grid_to_search = {}
        self.stride = 8
        self.grid_to_search_x = x * self.stride + self.search_size // 2
        self.grid_to_search_y = y * self.stride + self.search_size // 2
```

Any idea would be helpful. Thanks a lot